# Gradle assemble failing due to "Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'. "

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework, capacitor, buildozer

I tried to make my ionic project into a .apk, following the below steps

```
$ ionic start
$ ionic build
$ ionic capacitor add android
$ ionic sync
$ cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

extra info

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2012-12-21 00:00:00 UTC
Revision:     none

Groovy:       2.4.16
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.5 compiled on August 27 2018
JVM:          10 ("Oracle Corporation" 10+44)
OS:           Linux 5.4.119-14943-gff839c7fedcc amd64
```

after which I got the following error, how do I fix this?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/1.2.0/appcompat-1.2.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/1.2.0/appcompat-1.2.0.pom'.
> > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 18s

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: just use google collab for compiling u wont have issues